# How to Loop Userform Controls Events?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, userform

I want a loop for userform controls events.

I have six image items;

```
button1
button1_hover 
button2 
button2_hover 
button3 
button3_hover
```

I used the event called MouseMove to create a hover statement. I used this method like this;

```
Private Sub button1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

button1.Visible = False
button1_hover.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub button2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

button2.Visible = False
button2_hover.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub button3_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

button3.Visible = False
button3_hover.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

For i = 1 To 4
 Me.Controls("button" & i).Visible = True
 Me.Controls("button" & i & "_hover").Visible = False
 Me.Controls("button" & i & "_click").Visible = False
Next

End Sub
```

It works but I want to use the three mousemove events in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom class to capture the `MouseMove` for the controls you're interested in.  Here's a simple example which just swaps out the backcolor for command buttons.

Your use case would be a little more complex, but the same basic approach would work.

```
Option Explicit

Private colButtons As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim ctl
    Set colButtons = New Collection
    'loop over controls and look for buttons (for example)
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton" Then
            colButtons.Add getHover(ctl) 'create an instance of hover using ctl
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function getHover(ctl)
    Dim rv As New hover
    Set rv.btn = ctl
    Set getHover = rv
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                               ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim o As hover
    'clear all the button backcolors in colButtons
    For Each o In colButtons
        o.btn.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    Next o
End Sub
```

Custom class `hover` - objects of this class hold a reference to the provided control and capture its `MouseMove` event

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton '<< note WithEvents

Private Sub btn_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                          ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    btn.BackColor = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dude, I dont really know how can I use classes vba I will learn and make this code happen as well as I want :) I update code in here. You make me look in different vision. thx

Answer (score 1):

With help of Tim Williams i finished it.

In userform codes look like;

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Set userform_index = Me '' I set user form item to call it another module
    Call Functions.Button_Hover
End Sub
```

Also I create module named Functions. The Functions Code as below;

```
Option Explicit
Public col_button As Collection
Public userform_index As UserForm
Public temp_ctl
Sub Run()
Main_Page.Show
End Sub
Function Button_Hover()
           Set col_button = New Collection '' Crate a collection which carry item in it.
            For Each temp_ctl In userform_index.Controls '' Checking every toolbox item in exist userform
                If Len(temp_ctl.Name) = 7 And TypeName(temp_ctl) = "Image" Then
                '' ^^I have image called button1 also button1_hover. I sparate that with it. (takes only button1)^^
                    col_button.Add getHover(temp_ctl) '' used interested image in function called gethover
                End If
            Next
            col_button.Add getHover(userform_index) '' used userform in gethover function
End Function
Private Function getHover(temp_ctl) '' this func set hover as image or userform.
    Dim temp_hover As New hover
    
    If TypeName(temp_ctl) = "Image" Then
     Set temp_hover.btnimg = temp_ctl
     
    Else
     Set temp_hover.btnform = temp_ctl
     
    End If
    
     Set getHover = temp_hover
     
End Function
```

And... Big one :) class called hover makes loop everytime ı make mouse move on image or userform.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents btnimg As MSForms.Image
Public WithEvents btnform As MSForms.UserForm
Public button_index As Integer
Public button_count As Integer

Sub btnimg_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    button_index = Right(btnimg.Name, 1) ''gettin button index as i did. (Exp: button1 to 1)
    button_count = (col_button.Count) - 1 '' gettin button count decrease userform.
    userform_index.Controls("button" & button_index).Visible = False '' (Exp: button1.visible =false)
    userform_index.Controls("button" & button_index & "_hover").Visible = True '(Exp: button1_hover.visible =True)
   
End Sub

Sub btnform_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    button_count = (col_button.Count) - 1
    For button_index = 1 To button_count '' Set all button with no hover visible and make hovers invisible.
        userform_index.Controls("button" & button_index).Visible = True
        userform_index.Controls("button" & button_index & "_hover").Visible = False
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Final Result;
[image]

It works fine but i need update for more than 9 buttons :D. but it work for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

using textbox MouseMove procedure in **a class**, I made the background color of the text boxes change when the mouse cursor is hovered over the text boxes.

[image]

I added to UserForm the following codes:

```
Dim excelvba() As New Alltextboxes
Dim say As Integer, evn As Control
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    say = 1
    For Each evn In Me.Controls
      If TypeName(evn) = "TextBox" Then
         ReDim Preserve excelvba(1 To say)
         Set excelvba(say).TextGroup = evn
         say = say + 1
       End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    For Each evn In Me.Controls
      If TypeName(evn) = "TextBox" Then
         evn.BackColor = vbWhite
      End If
    Next evn
End Sub
```

[Source of sample file](https://eksi30.com/right-click-context-menu-on-text-boxes/)